# Conditional Formatting to Highlight Cells in Row if any number is present, but NOT if a formula or blank cell is present

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a conditional formatting rule that will highlight cells in a given row that contain a number only, but NOT a formula and NOT blank cells.

Example of the sheet:

| Number of cases assigned to Agent | Case Agent ID | Case Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1234 | 2345678 |
|  | 1234 | 2236789 |
|  | 1234 | 2312759 |
|  | 1234 | 2367842 |
| 3 | 5632 | 2198423 |
|  | 5632 | 1948863 |
|  | 5632 | 8574337 |

One cell in Row 1 SHOULD contain a formula like such: "=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)" which then prints the number of cases assigned to the particular case agent ID. However occasionally a new user of the sheet will just type "4" instead of ensuring the formula is entered in the first adjacent cell. However, we don't need all cells in row 1 to list the number of cases assigned to case agent, we just want one cell to contain that number.

Is there a way to use conditional formatting to change the background color of the cells in row 1 where the cell contains a plain number and leaves cells alone that are blank OR that contain a formula that prints a number? The hope is that this color change will prompt users to make sure the formula is present in row 1 instead of just typing the number of cases they just entered into the spreadsheet?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It sounds like you are confusing columns with rows. In the table you show, row `1` contains headings. Column `A` contains the numbers `4` and `3`, together with five blank values.

Answer (score 0):

To format cells in `A2:A` that contain a number but do not contain a formula, ignoring blank cells, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule:

```
=isnumber(A2) * not(isformula(A2)) * not(isblank(A2))
```

To *prevent* entering a plain number in the column in the first place, use this custom formula rule with **Data > Data validation** for the range `A2:A`:

```
=isnumber(A2) * isformula(A2)
```

Click **Advanced options** and choose **Reject the input** to finish the rule.

The rule will prevent entering numbers or text in those cells, and will only accept formulas that produce a number.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)